# How to calculate percentage of list of objects based some value in java

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a list of Portfolio objects in java collection. This Portfolio object has a property called scoringRule. I want to calculate how much percentage of Portfolio objects are present in the list for each type of scoringRule. Actually, I have only 2 different types of scoring rules. The scoringRUle property can be either "single" or "double". How can I do this?

```
Class Portfolio{
private String name;
private String type;
private String scoringRule;
}

 List<Portfolio> portfolios = new ArrayList<Portfolio>();
```

Comment: A `Map<String,Integer>` could be used to maintain a count of the occurrences of each scoring rule. Then divide counts by total.

Comment: Actually, my list is already populated with portfolios. My final requirement is based on the calculated percentage I want to retrieve bunch of elements from the list according to that percentage. SO, for example if my list has 50 elements with 40% single scoring and 60% double scoring then I want to retrieve 10 elements each time for 5 times from this list which is proportion of that percentages.i.e 4 single and 6 double.

Comment: Yes, but the idea is to scan the existing portfolio list and create `scoringRule` counts from that (either that or count scoring rules as you build the portfolio list; either way same idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution.

```
    double single = 0;
    double doublee = 0;
    for (Portfolio pobj : portfolios) {
        if(pobj.scoringRule.equals("single"))
            single++;
        else
            doublee++;
    }
    System.out.println("single Percentage : " +(single / list.size() )*100);
    System.out.println("doublee Percentage : " + (doublee / list.size())*100);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I now retrieve 10 elements each time which are proportion of this percentages from this list?